# Win7-64 %windir%, %path% environment variables disappear, can't reload

Tags: windows-7-x64

I am having recurring intermittent problems with "losing" my environment variables, most onerously %windir% and %path%. The problem occurs when I have locked the keyboard and log back in. Rebooting the system (cold- and warm-boot) does not *reliably* bring them back, but eventually multiple iterations of booting has (so far) brought everything back.

If I open a command window and type **echo %windir%** and **echo %path%** and find that the variables exist and are properly defined, *and if I leave that command window open*, I can leave my system running for days without a problem.

I have captured the results of **set** to list all envars, both when the system is broken, and when it is fixed. The broken list is much shorter (%windir% is not even defined, %path% contains the definition from registry HKCU\Environment, but not from HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Environment).

I am guessing that the boot-up process is getting sidetracked.

Spent all morning with Geek Squad but they had no concrete suggestions. (They did suggest "taking the computer back to a previous restore point", but I fear that could cause more problems... and they didn't have confidence it would help.)

Do I have any options beyond possibly reinstalling everything?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS tech support.

Answer (score 0):

I did finally find the answer, and although I understand this subject was closed by the commenter, I thought others might want to know. This link explains it pretty well:

https://superuser.com/questions/355594/windows-7s-path-and-environment-variables-are-corrupted

The short version is this: My system PATH exceeded a Windows maximum of 2048 bytes (it was more than 2200 bytes long). When that happens, the boot process fails to instantiate PATH and WINDIR.

The "fix" was to run c:\windows\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe from a command prompt (because without WINDIR, you can't open the Control Panel app for environment variables), and manually extract anything from the PATH I thought I could live without, until I whittled the PATH string down to under 2048 bytes.